# General form and basis for $B_2$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to find the general form of the element $B_2$ and work out the basis for $B_2$ also. Would somebody be able to start me off please? I don't want the answer I just wanna know the method of doing it. $$B_2=\{X\in M_5(\mathbb{C})|X^TS+SX=0\}$$
$$S\in M_5(\mathbb{C})$$
$$S=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&1 \\
0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a basis by computing $E_{ij}^TS+SE_{ij}$ for each $i,j$ (where $E_{ij}$ is the standard unit matrix with $1$ in the $(i,j)$-entry and $0$'s elsewhere). Once you've computed these expressions, you can find certain combinations that yield $0$.

For example, consider $E_{12} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. We get $E_{12}^TS+SE_{12} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ (so $E_{12}$ itself isn't in $B_2$).

Now try other standard unit vectors and you'll see that $E_{41}$ yields the same thing as $E_{12}$. Therefore, $A=E_{12}-E_{41}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ yields $A^TS+SA=0$ and thus $A=E_{12}-E_{41} \in B_2$.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. Is there a "quick" way of finding all the basis, because there are 10, or do I just have to try all of them doing this method?

Comment: If you work with $E_{ij}$'s long enough, you can make this technique a "quick" way:  $S = E_{11}+E_{24}+E_{35}+E_{42}+E_{53}$. Products between $E_{ij}E_{kl} = 0$ unless $j=k$ and then it's $E_{il}$.

Comment: Notice the pairings of $2$ and $4$ as well as $3$ and $5$. This helps us see which pairs should work well.

Comment: I see, okay I understand now. Also, what would be the general form of the element of $B_2$, as in what does that mean? Thank you

Comment: That's not an easy question to answer. B2 is one of a string of algebras of type B. These along with type D algebras correspond to the orthogonal Lie groups. These are the isometries preserving Euclidean structure.